# What's the difference between these two LSTM implementation in tensorflow,how to initialize 8 weight matrices of LSTM?

Tags: python, matrix, tensorflow, deep-learning, lstm

I'm confused about how to define weight matrices for LSTM. As there are are 8 weight matrices for the LSTM, I don't know how to initialize those weight matrices for a LSTM in tensorflow.

But then I came across this [implementation](https://github.com/KnHuq/Dynamic-Tensorflow-Tutorial/blob/master/LSTM/LSTM.ipynb), which makes complete sense, as it has all the 8 weight matrices, but it doesn't use tensorflow implementation of LSTM. It is consistent with the LSTM equations. But in the tensorflow [implementation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/rnn_cell.html#LSTMCell) of LSTM I don't know how to define all those 8 weight matrices as they are defined in the first above implementation.

Could you please help me out?

Comment: This [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/tutorials/recurrent/index.html) might help

Answer (score 0):

**First thing first:** If you take a close look, there aren't exactly 8 matrices but 14 in total. 4 * 3 matrices of W, U (parameter matrices) and b (bias vector) for *`Input Gate, Forget Gate, Cell State and Output State`*. In addition, there are two more matrices W and b for `dense layer`.

Now coming to actual question, I presume that you would like to know how these matrices are initialized in Tensorflow.

**I am answering questions wrt Tensorflow v1.2.**

**Quick Answer:** Use [TF-api for LSTM](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.2/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/rnn/LSTMCell) which has a parameter called `initializer` to be used for initializing weight and projection matrices.

> By default, bias vector is initialized to zero vector and kernel
>   initializers are initialized randomly using uniform distribution.

Now to take a look at where W and b are used, you need to dig little deeper inside the code. I will provide few checkpoints for the same.

- Method call to evaluate the multiplications: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/3686ef0d51047d2806df3e2ff6c1aac727456c1d/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py#L576

  `lstm_matrix = _linear([inputs, m_prev], 4 * self._num_units, bias=True)`
- Actual computation: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/3686ef0d51047d2806df3e2ff6c1aac727456c1d/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py#L1051

  `weights = vs.get_variable(
      _WEIGHTS_VARIABLE_NAME, [total_arg_size, output_size],
      dtype=dtype,
      initializer=kernel_initializer)`

  Here. instead of 4 separate multiplications, a single multiplication is performed and then the matrix is split into 4 parts.

> So, in nutshell, Tensorflow does initialization automatically for you.
>   In case if you don't want to go with default initializers, you have
>   flexibility to provide other options.